# The navbar with the content - how to keep the 100vh size?

Tags: html, css, layout, styling

Below is a reproduction of the issue which I am struggling with.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/5n4Lhgbt/

As you can see the `section` div is a little higher than the 100vh (the height of the navbar has been added & the scrollbar occurs). I want to avoid it. The situation which I am talking about is clearly shown in the image below:

[image]

A few pieces of information:

- the height of the navbar is dynamic - it could be higher, depends on the logo inside,
- using the `overflow: hidden` on the section container doesn't satisfy me,

I appreciate any help.

Comment: overflow hidden does not prevent an overflow. it just disables the scrollbar. means you cant see a scrollbar nor use it. If you want to hide the scrollbar itself without losing the scroll ability, you should give it a width or height of `none`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add to your `#section` :

```
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
```

and that would make the trick: [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/yqs50rva/)

Comment: Ahh, it seems that I overcomplicated the problem... Thank you for the solution! That's exactly what I needed!

Comment: Np. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

change your `#section` css to this:

```
#section {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 3.25rem);
  background-color: green;
}
```

This will subtract  navbar height from the section and make it's height equal to the remaining space.